# Eclipse doesn't recocnize ImageView or AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

When I type *ImageView* or *AnimationDrawable* I get a string of errors proclaiming:

AnimationDrawable cannot be resolved to a type.

line 14 Java Problem

I don't understand, do I need to create another class? Or do the AnimationDrawables just not go in the *filename*.java?

And if I do need to create another class, can you show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you importing those clases?

```
// this must be placed at beginning of your file
// after the 'package' statemen
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
```

If you are using Eclipse, you don't need to manually *import* those classes: you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and it will automatically add the *imports* statements that you need (it will also remove the ones that you are not using).

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to declare the view that you are using
like, for imageview

```
import android.widget.ImageView
```

likewise for textview,

```
import android.widget.TextView
```